# How to store values(key, value) pair in a word document

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am developing a word add-in using word JavaScript API. I need to store some values in context of a document so when i open a document again on same client or other client, want to get that values from document and perform some actions. I have tried it with settings object but Settings object are saved per add-in and per document so values are not available on other clients add-in. Please guide me how i can store the values that will be available everywhere with document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Custom Document Properties.

Take a look here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec/reference/word/custompropertycollection.md

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am using "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" and it showing customPropertyObject undefined. Please advice.

Comment: make sure you have the latest update.You need build 16.7766+

Answer (score 1):

You can also store an XML part with all the data you need, basically an XML file stored within the document. Check out this sample on how to add and retrieve xml parts. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Work-with-custom-XML-parts/blob/master/C%23/CustomXMLAppWeb/App/Home/Home.js

btw i would recomend you to use document properties it seems to be more adequate for your needs. Make sure you use the latest updates in Word!

Here is an example on how to create a document property (first example a numeric value, second one a string):

```js
function insertNumericProperty() { 
        Word.run(function (context) {
            context.document.properties.customProperties.add("Numeric Property", 1234);
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Property added");     
                })
                .catch(function (e) { 
                    console.log(e.message);
                })
        })

    }

    function insertStringProperty() { 
        Word.run(function (context) {
            context.document.properties.customProperties.add("String Property", "Hello World!");
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("Property added");     
                })
                .catch(function (e) { 
                    console.log(e.message);
                })
        })
    }
```

Here is code on how to retrieve them:

```js
function readCustomDocumentProperties() { 
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var properties = context.document.properties.customProperties;
            context.load(properties);
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < properties.items.length; i++)
                        console.log("Property Name:" + properties.items[i].key + ";Type=" + properties.items[i].type +"; Property Value=" + properties.items[i].value);
                })
                .catch(function (e) { 
                    console.log(e.message);
                })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have followed the above link but not able to add, edit & delete the key/value pair in the document. Can you please provide me some working code that will help me a lot.Thanks.

Comment: the code above is functional, the idea is that you save an XML document with all the name/value pairs you need. At this point i would recommend you to try custom document properties, it seems to be a better solution for what you want to do.

Comment: i added more details on how you can create and read custom document properties. thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply with sample code, it's working well :)
Where i can find more about 'customProperties'.

Comment: in the link that Philip shared on the first answer! let me know if you have additional questions.